# how to update content of an fragment without updating whole App

Tags: android

I am making an app for my college as a minor project. I have included Notice Board Fragment in it. But i don't know How to update content of Notice board without updating whole app.
[image]

I want to make notice board fragment like this. Just tell me in brief after that i will do it myself. Or You can tell me whole coding and procedures. I will really appreciate your help

Comment: I presume you want to update the data on the fragment. Why not use [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [Observers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer) for that?

Comment: no, This way will not gonna work in my case

Comment: which time do you need to update content of fragment?

Comment: I want to update content when i have to some notice on noticeBoard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change fragment, you should use this:

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.commit();
```

Comment: no i dont want to change fragment. I want to update it.